# Guardar el valor de una celda de una Base de Datos en una variable en Java

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, variables

Lo que quiero es almacenar en una variable un valor ya registrado en una base de datos, para en el código poder sumarle, restarle, etc. y devolver otro valor, pero no sé como.

```
     int agregado;
     agregado=Integer.parseInt (txtCantidadE.getText());
        
     int resultado;
     resultado=agregado+***¿¿¿variable_con_el_dato_sql???***;

    ***¿¿¿variable_con_el_dato_sql=???;***
```

El agregado es un numero que digita el usuario.

El resultado es la suma del agregado, más lo que ya hay en la base de datos.

La "variable_con_el_dato_sql" es donde quiero almacenar el dato.

Y el procedimiento para obtener ese dato es lo que no sé como hacer

Comment: Tienes que hacer una consulta a la base de datos y obtener el valor leyendo el `ResultSet` que arrojará la consulta. Aquí mismo hay varios ejemplos sobre cómo hacerlo. Consulta alguno, implementa el código y si tienes problemas nos dices.

Comment: Para guardar y extrar datos desde una base de datos en Java tienes que usar JDBC. Este ejemplo muestra cómo hacerlo: https://www.technicalkeeda.com/jdbc-tutorials/jdbc-preparedstatement-select-query-example